# Mocking a random return value in ASP.NET MVC for SpecFlow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mocking, ui-automation, specflow

I am using Specflow and WebDriver to test my ASP.Net MVC application.

I would like to use mocks with ASP.Net MVC in my high level Specflow tests. This would be used to set the app into a known state.

Within the ASP.Net app, there is a class, with a method that returns a random value. I would like to mock this class so that I know what value will be returned, and I know what to expect in the tests.

Note this can't be done through the use of database data. The randomness is not effected by the database.

I understand this can be done in lower level tests (like controller tests, and other unit tests) however I would like to know how can I do this from Specflow. Some form of Dependency Injection would be good.

I have read about Deleporter, but that project seems to be inactive. If it's not, then please correct me.

Do you have any pointers for me?

Thanks

Comment: do you want to change the state of your deployed website?

Comment: Either that, or it could be self hosted, or hosted in-memory. As long as I can run tests against it.

Comment: @Daryn: Maybe you could change the title of your question to something like "Mocking random value in ASP.NET MVC for SpecFlow"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Since you need to know a random value in SpecFlow from within your MVC application, you don't want a "mock," instead, you need a stub (and some chicken voodoo magic).

### Stubbing a random value in ASP.NET MVC so SpecFlow can use it

1. Create an interface that your random value generator will implement
2. Create another class in your MVC project that implements this interface, but returns a known value that your SpecFlow tests can use
3. Add an `<appSetting>` in the `App.config` file for your MVC application allowing you to specify the concrete class that returns this random value
4. Create a factory class in your MVC app that reads the configuration setting and returns an object implementing your random value interface:

The interfaces and classes below are just an example for you to follow. I'm assuming you are generating a random `int` but the following solution could be used as a template to solve your problem.

#### Create the interface

This simple interface just has a single method that returns an `int`. Nothing else.

```
public interface IRandomValueGenerator
{
    int GenerateRandomValue();
}
```

#### Create the classes to implement the interface

You'll want to create your "stub" class that returns a known value, and make sure your existing class implements the interface.

First, the fake random number generator which returns a consistent value for testing purposes:

```
public class FakeRandomValueGenerator : IRandomValueGenerator
{
    public int GenerateRandomValue()
    {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Now, make sure your real class implements this interface:

```
public class RealRandomValueGenerator : IRandomValueGenerator
{
    public int GenerateRandomValue()
    {
        return new System.Random().Next();
    }
}
```

#### Add a setting to App.config

Next, you want to make your random value generator configurable, so that in production you are using the real generator, but in your integration testing environment you are using the stub:

App.config

```
<appSettings>
  <!--
    Values:
    - random (for deployed sites)
    - fake (for the integration testing environment)
  -->
  <add key="randomValueGenerator" value="fake" />
```

### Create the factory class to return a value generator

The last step is creating a factory class that reads your configuration and returns a concrete type for the `IRandomValueGenerator` interface.

```
public static class RandomValueGeneratorFactory
{
    public static IRandomValueGenerator GetGenerator()
    {
        string type = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["randomValueGenerator"];
        IRandomValueGenerator valueGenerator;

        switch (type)
        {
            case "random":
                valueGenerator = new RealRandomValueGenerator();
                break;
            case "fake":
                valueGenerator = new FakeRandomValueGenerator();
                break;
            default:
                throw new System.Configuration.ConfigurationException("Unsupported value for randomValueGenerator: " + type);
        }

        return valueGenerator;
    }
}
```

#### Putting the pieces together

Now you need to change your MVC application code to use the factory:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        IRandomValueGenerator generator = RandomValueGeneratorFactory.GetGenerator();
        int value = generator.GenerateRandomValue();

        // Do other stuff

        return View(...);
    }
}
```

#### Dependency Injection

You mentioned that dependency injection would be a good solution. By declaring an interface for generating the random number you are setting yourself up for dependency injection -- but I leave this as an exercise for you!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. As stated in my question, using a database is not an option. I have a class that is non-deterministic. This class is not effected by the database in any way. I want to mock or stub this functionality. This will allow me to test the remainder of the application.

Comment: @Daryn: Can you update your question with some more information about this "non-deterministic" class? Can you also give us the use case for this class? That might help in crafting a solution.

Comment: @Daryn: I have completely rewritten my answer based on the edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly cannot achieve what with a database then an ugly option could be to allow your tests to call your webpages with an optional url parameter which specifies the test config to use, then in your code select an implementation based on the value in this parameter(s). This is probably something you only want to do in debug versions of the code, and don't want to allow in production.

Alternatively you could have a distinct URL to call to set the test state for the application and then your other urls don't need to change and the test URL could just be excluded from production. You could then call this from the specflow steps (probably in a `Given I am using test state 'someConfigName'`).

You might also get some value if you can use ASP vNext as a self-hosted solution is possible.  With this it should be possible to have specflow use a `[Before]` step to set up the self host and an `[After]` step to tear it down. Without ASP vNext I don't think self hosted is a possibility.